# react native run android red screen on genymotion virtual device, windows

Tags: android, windows, react-native, genymotion

I am running this command

```
C:\Program Files\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
```

And get this:

[image]

Sometimes I get this:

[image]

I tried to enter my ip in dev settings of virtual device

[image]

But it didn't help. How do I fix this?

upd:so as suggested below, I ran `react-native start` in another console.
And first it worked, but then I went out for a couple of hours, came home and the same error continued appearing.

and this is the output of `react-native start`:

> Looking for JS files in    C:\Program Files\AwesomeProject
>
> [22:02:56]  Building Dependency Graph [22:02:56] 
>   Crawling File System [22:02:56]  Loading bundles layout
>   [22:02:56]    Loading bundles layout (2ms)
>
> React packager ready.
>
> [22:03:25]    Crawling File System (29488ms) [22:03:25] 
>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript [22:03:27]    Building
>   in-memory fs for JavaScript (1105ms) [22:03:27]  Building
>   in-memory fs for Assets [22:03:28]    Building in-memory fs for
>   Assets (1219ms) [22:03:28]  Building Haste Map [22:03:28]
>    Building (deprecated) Asset Map [22:03:29]    Building
>   (deprecated) Asset Map (172ms) [22:03:34]    Building Haste Map
>   (6447ms) [22:03:34]    Building Dependency Graph (38281ms)

Comment: Is this on an emulator or a device?

Comment: @Martin Konicek on emulator

Answer (score 0):

When you are developing with react-native from cmd-line you have to keep the development server running only to update the code, which `run-android` does by default. But if you somehow killed that, you can restart it with just

`react-native start`

Both your errors indicate the same thing: that the dev server is not running or not connected. I find my setup requires a port reversal to hook up the dev server. Perhaps that's the issue.

`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: it worked, but then I went out.Came home a couple of hours laters and now still see the same error even with react-native start.See updated question for details

Comment: Everything you posted from the console is normal. Is it the case you receive the second red screen sometimes even after `react-native start ` ?

Comment: i can't debug your error but suggest you try updating react-native. It's new technology so it's best to keep up with latest.